# Multiple rows to one item in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, row

I have some PHP that retrieves data from a database table and populates an array depending on a query.

I want to merge two fields together, they are 'organisation' and 'full address' and store this in one item under 'ADDRESS'. How can I add both rows together?

I have tried 'ADDRESS' => $row['organisation'] + $row['full_address'], but I don't think I am looking along the correct lines.

```
    <?php

if (isset($_GET['query'])) {
    // Connect to our database
    $conn = pg_connect("host=myhost port=myport dbname=mydb user=myuser password=mypass");

    // Retrieve the query
    $query = $_GET['query'];

    // Search the database for all similar items
    $sql = pg_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM addresses.llpg_basic WHERE (lpi_logical_status_desc = 'Approved / Preferred LPI' OR lpi_logical_status_desc = 'Provisional LPI') AND full_address ILIKE '%{$query}%'");
    $array = array();

    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $address = array(
        'ADDRESS' => $row['full_address'],
        'POSTCODE' => $row['postcode'],
        'UPRN' => $row['uprn'],
        'USRN' => $row['usrn'],
        'X' => $row['xref'],
        'Y' => $row['yref']
        );
        array_push($array, $address);
    }

    sort($array);

    $jsonstring = json_encode($array);

    // Return the json array
    echo $jsonstring;
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: have you tried `'ADDRESS' => $row['organisation'] .$row['full_address'],`

Comment: Maybe at ``'ADDRESS' => $row['organisation'] + $row['full_address']`` you mean to try use ``'ADDRESS' => $row['organisation'] . ' ' . $row['full_address']``. the ``.`` is the concatenate operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can [concatenate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) your columns :

```
$sql = pg_query($conn, "SELECT *, full_address || ',' || organisation AS concatenated_string FROM addresses.llpg_basic  WHERE (lpi_logical_status_desc = 'Approved / Preferred LPI' OR lpi_logical_status_desc = 'Provisional LPI') AND full_address ILIKE '%{$query}%");
```

or using concat function :

```
$sql = pg_query($conn, "SELECT *, concat(full_address,' ', organisation) AS concatenated_string FROM addresses.llpg_basic  WHERE (lpi_logical_status_desc = 'Approved / Preferred LPI' OR lpi_logical_status_desc = 'Provisional LPI') AND full_address ILIKE '%{$query}%");
```

after that you may access your concatenated string as :

```
'ADDRESS' => $row['concatenated_string'],
```

---

Either, if you need to [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) strings in php you need to use `periods` instead of plus

```
'ADDRESS' => $row['organisation'] . $row['full_address'],
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
'ADDRESS' => $row['organisation'] . "\n" . $row['full_address'],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your query like this:

```
`$sql = pg_query($conn, "SELECT *, concat(organisation,", ",full_address) myfull_address FROM addresses.llpg_basic WHERE (lpi_logical_status_desc = 'Approved / Preferred LPI' OR lpi_logical_status_desc = 'Provisional LPI') AND full_address ILIKE '%{$query}%'");`
```